# Cipher.getInstance slow with Java 8

Tags: java, encryption

I've had a client application currently running well on `Java 7`. In the near future, it has to be run on `Java 8`. If I change `JRE` to version 8 the application is still running without errors, but it's performance degrades. This is is also true if I compile it for `Java 8`. As I have found, one of the issues is the following statement

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
```

With `Java 7` it takes `1300` milliseconds on average, with `Java 8` about `2200`. That is not much for one call but it adds up for thousands of calls. Because every client call runs in its own `VM` the cipher instance can not be reused (without rewriting the whole application).

Is there a way to increase performance?

Comment: Are those calls that short that a second more makes that much of a difference? In that case wouldn't it be wise to reuse the VMs in general as starting up a VM would cost even more (at least that's what my intuition tells me)?

Comment: Why don't you keep the instance of `cypher`, rather than calling `Cypher.getInstance()` again and again ?

Comment: @Benoit he actually addressed it: "Because every client call runs in its own VM the cipher instance can not be reused".

Comment: You should check if your Java7 installation was modified to specify `/./dev/urandom` as PRNG, which could explain a large delta in performance. That's the `securerandom.source` param defined in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file. Looks like it can also be defined through the `-Djava.security.egd` system property

Comment: I can understand your disappointment. I mean, 2.2 seconds is longer than it takes the attacker to decrypt your DES encryption!

Comment: @Thomas: If you are running multiple VMs most likely the reason is the first-time initialization of JCE, not the Cipher.getInstance() code.

Comment: @Robert well, that would be another argument for reusing VMs :)

Comment: @Robert: Yes, most of that time is one-time class loading I suspect, Java 8 classes are more sophisticated and larger

Comment: Thank you all for your comments :-)
There is no difference for securerandom.source between 7 and 8. And there is realy not much difference in response time for different input values for Cipher.getInstance(). 
You are right, rewriting would be the best solution, but it is an old application that will be replaced in near future. Therefore, my customer does not  want to invest much effort...